# A batch file to move the most recent folders first?

Tags: windows, shell, powershell, batch-file

A batch file to move the most recent folders first?

For example i have a batch file which moves folders from my local machine to a remote machine, is there a way to move the most recent created folders first?

Currently i have the following:

```
xcopy /s C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\AutoFrameworkResults \\192.1xx.1.xx\xxxx\xxxxx\Common\AutoFrameworkResults
```

[image]

thanks for your help

Comment: @Melebius thanks would i add the code after the xcopy?

Comment: @Melebius you have already given the right direction :-)

Comment: thanks all for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might be too late to the party but here is the script anyway.

```
setlocal
set "sourceDir=c:\users\xxxx\desktop\autoframeworkresults"
set "destDir=\\192.1xx.1xx\xxxx\xxxx\common\autoframeworkresults"

for /f "delims=" %%d in ('dir "%sourceDir%" /o-d /ad /b') do (
  xcopy /s "%sourceDir%\%%d" "%destDir%\%%d\"
)
```

Comment: how do i turn recursive off, so dosnt keep prompting to overwrite the file? thanks again

Comment: I don't really know what you mean with recursive in the given context but you could add the */y* switch to the xcopy command to suppress  prompting to overwrite an existing destination file.

Comment: thats exactly what i was looking for @treintje thanks i will add behind the xcopy